# String concatenation with or without .ToString()?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a statement where a string is assigned in the following manner:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
{
    Foo.MyStringProperty = "Bar_" + i.ToString();
    /* ... */
}
```

Are there any performance differences between `i.ToString()` or just plain `i`, as both are just converted to the (culture invariant?) string equivalent?

I am well aware of the existence of `String.Concat()`, `String.Format`, `StringBuilder`, etc., but for the sake of this case, lets assume I may only use `+` concatenation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you make a testapplication? Let it loop for 10.000 times, measure the time and you know the answer.

Comment: Caveat: `ToString()` uses the current culture. If you want culture-independent conversion you would have to use `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` (This is more important when dealing with floating point numbers than with integers).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`+` concatenation uses `String.Concat` anyway - `String` itself doesn't expose a + operator.

So for example:

```
int i = 10;
string x = "hello" + i;
```

is compiled into:

```
int i = 10;
object o1 = "hello";
object o2 = i; // Note boxing
string x = string.Concat(o1, o2);
```

Whereas calling `ToString` directly will avoid boxing and call the `Concat(string, string)` overload. Therefore the version with the `ToString` call will be *slightly* more efficient - but I highly doubt that it'll be significant, and I'd strongly urge you to go with whichever version you feel is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer. Though I'd be tempted to accept divo's comment if it were an answer instead, because of his caveat about the culture info.

Comment: In my testing the boxing and unboxing of a value type when NOT using the ToString method causes about a 2.5% performance hit.

Comment: Interesting. I thought maybe the C# compiler would generate the same IL in the two situations, but you're right, it doesn't (not with C# 5 either). The situation with a reference type is a little different. Here the code `"hello" + obj` will not throw even if `obj` is a null reference. But `"hello" + obj.ToString()` will throw if `obj` is null, of course. However, even with reference types the style with explicit `.ToString()` could theoretically be faster (when `obj` is non-null) because it uses the `Concat(string, string)` overload instead of the `Concat(object, object)` overload.

Answer (score 6):

Just using `string + object` forces a call to ToString() on the object - it's equivalent to calling it explicitly.

Comment: @Aviad: There's a difference in timing, however - which affects whether the value is boxed or not.

Answer (score 2):

ToString is the default method used to write an object. So, if you use "i" or "i.ToString()" is the same thing.

If you know a little about operator overloading in c++ you can understand how "+" works in this case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int number = 10;
        string msg = "age is " + number + ".";
        msg += " great?";
        Console.WriteLine("msg: {0}", msg);

        String s1 = 10 + 5 + ": Two plus three is " + 2 + 3;
        String s2 = 10 + 5 + ": Two plus three is " + (2 + 3);
        Console.WriteLine("s1: {0}", s1);
        Console.WriteLine("s2: {0}", s2);    }

}
```

**Result:**
msg: age is 10. great?

s1: 15: Two plus three is 23

s2: 15: Two plus three is 5

Answer (score 0):

I would use .ToString() out of habit and readability, I am sure you will find better performance saving elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Jon Skeet, the point about boxing is very important!

If you use explicitly *ToString()* there is no boxing, which means that no object-box is created around i. The object box around i has to be thrown away later on by the Garbage Collector, causing a performance penalty.

If you are doing it only a few times in your program it does not matter, but if you are boxing very often, you should go for the *ToString()* version.