# Converting Doubles to strings

Tags: c#, string

When I remove the `ToString()` in the method below, I get no error, so why is it necessary?

```
public string BuildEquation()
{
    switch (Choice)
    {
        case "A":
            return mNumber1.ToString() + "+" + mNumber2.ToString();
        case "S":
            return mNumber1.ToString() + "-" + mNumber2.ToString();
        case "M":
            return mNumber1.ToString() + "*" + mNumber2.ToString();
        default:
            return mNumber1.ToString() + "/" + mNumber2.ToString(); // corrected
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the data types of `mNumber1` and `mNumber2`? And what error are you talking about? Be more specific.

Comment: Who or what said it was necessary?

Comment: it may also make sense if you would show the defined datatype of Number2 and mNumber2 if they are strings already then you do not need the `.ToString()`

Comment: The NUmber1 and Number2 are doubles. I was just assuming that because the method returns a string that I would need to convert the doubles to a string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974776/string-concatenation-with-or-without-tostring

Comment: You've provided convincing evidence that it is not necessary, so I don't understand why you're asking the question.

Comment: So you're asking us to tell you why you think a conversion is necessary?

Comment: He is asking for the purpose for `ToString()` in a specific case. Ok, fair enough, he could formulate his question better, but I've seen far worse formulation on SO. The answer finds it's way to explaining the C# specification. Not something you'd expect every C# developer to know by heart. So, is it really such a bad question that it deserves so many downvotes? Or am I the only one who wonders that. Instead of the downvotes, comment to help the poor dude (or dudette) to improve the question... +1 from my side, for what it's worth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatening `double` and `string` together converts it for you.

Otherwise you can convert it with `.ToString()`

Or use Convert.ToString(double) method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c309e6c9.aspx

Comment: So I dont really need the ToString() method here then, thanks

Answer (score 7):

From the C# Language Specification 1.2, §7.7.4, Addition operator:

> String concatenation: The binary + operator performs string
>   concatenation when one or both operands are of type string. If an
>   operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is
>   substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its
>   string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method
>   inherited from type object. If ToString returns null, an empty string
>   is substituted. [...] A System.OutOfMemoryException may be thrown if
>   there is not enough memory available to allocate the resulting
>   string.

In other words, the + operand will do the ToString conversion for you.

Comment: ' return mNumber1.ToString() + "+";' works. 
'return mNumber1.ToString() + "+" + mNumber2.ToString();' works,
'return mNumber1;'  Error: Cannot implicitly convert type double to string

Answer (score 6):

> so why is it necessary?

It's not necessary.

Some people may subjectively consider it more readable to include it, but omitting it not only doesn't result in any errors, but it also produces the exact same output.  There is no functional change in omitting the `ToString` calls.

Comment: Actually, if `mNumber1` was a reference type, and if `mNumber1` was `null`, then `mNumber1.ToString() + "/"` would throw an exception because of the explicit `.ToString()`, while `mNumber1 + "/"` would not throw (the "sum" would be just `"/"`). But if `mNumber1` is a value type (which one would think based on the context), this comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are concatenating with a string already ("+", "-", etc), which means the rest of the expression is resolved to a string type. If you didn't concatenate those extra strings, then you would need to call `ToString()`.