# c# - Changing a string inside of an if statement isn't working

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I have this in game command so here it is

```
internal class GambleCommand : Command
{
    public GambleCommand() : base("roll", 3)
    {
    }

    protected override bool Process(Player player, RealmTime time, string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Length == 1)
            {

                int num = int.Parse(args[0]);
                Random rnd = new Random();
                string pl = player.Name;
                string rand = rnd.Next(0, num).ToString();

                if (num < 0)
                {
                    rand = rnd.Next(num, 0).ToString();
                }

                foreach (Client i in player.Manager.Clients.Values)
                {
                    i.SendPacket(new TextPacket
                    {
                        BubbleTime = 0,
                        Stars = -1,
                        Name = pl,
                        Text = "rolled a " + rand + " out of " + num + "."
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string pl = player.Name;
            string rand = rnd.Next(0, 100).ToString();
            foreach (Client i in player.Manager.Clients.Values)
            {
                i.SendPacket(new TextPacket
                {
                    BubbleTime = 0,
                    Stars = -1,
                    Name = pl,
                    Text = "rolled a " + rand
                });
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Everything here works fine except for the part that says

```
if (num < 0)
{
    rand = rnd.Next(num, 0).ToString();
}
```

Basically what this should do is change places from (0, num) num being the maximum number to (num, 0) if the number you choose is a negative. As of right now when I put a negative it goes to default 0-100 which is the catch statement.

Comment: Is args[0]  for sure a number?

Comment: string rand = rnd.Next(0, num).ToString();   What if num is negative ? you have to check it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rnd.next takes minimum value followed by maximum value.

```
int num = int.Parse(args[0]);
Random rnd = new Random();
string pl = player.Name;
string rand = rnd.Next(0, num).ToString();//Exception since negative value is less than 0
if (num < 0)
{
    rand = rnd.Next(num, 0).ToString();
}
```

Try this:

```
string rand = "";
if(num < 0)rand = rnd.Next(num, 0).ToString();
else rand = rnd.Next(0, num).ToString();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the maximum value is **exclusive** - so if you want numbers from `1` to `10` you need to call `rnd.Next(1, 11)`.

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting exception at line below when num value is negative:

```
 string rand = rnd.Next(0, num).ToString();
```

[image]

move statement above inside if block:

```
if (num < 0) string rand = rnd.Next(num, 0).ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

One more note:  This line ...

```
 Text = "rolled a " + rand + " out of " + num + "."
```

the  num   needs to be num.ToString() + "."

Comment: That's not true actually... It works fine either way in my game :P

Comment: @B3clawed it is true, it's just done by the compiler for you. The default for any object is to be boxed during concatenation with the base .ToString() method called for the type, as evidenced by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1974811. There are performance benefits to calling ToString() explicitly, but probably only in intensive string manipulation.